# how to change the url of the custom links in menu section - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I created a development site in a sub-folder. I changed the site url and base url of the site but the custom links in the menu section is not picking the new base url. it is still picking the old path. can some one help me.

Comment: can you tell me how you can change your old URL to new?

Comment: I changed t by running the queries in the database. I used the below queries 1. UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'ORIGINAL_URL', 'NEW_URL');
2 UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'ORIGINAL_URL', 'NEW_URL');
3 UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'ORIGINAL_URL', 'NEW_URL');
4 UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'ORIGINAL_URL', 'NEW_URL');

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will change only your domains URL but you need to change all links  follow instructions below:

**First method**

**1.** login to admin-end go to setting general setting

**2.** change your old website URL into home tab

**3.** change your old website site URL from site tab then same it.

Go to setting permalinks set default then save again change it to post name and then save.

**Second Method**

**1.** Open your PHPMyAdmin select your database

**2.** Open the table wp_options.

**3.** Change the site URL and admin URL from old to new.

Go to setting permalinks set default then save again change it to post name and then save.

For more information check this [link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings)

Thanks